# I got an XML file from asmx webservice, how do I bind it in the gridview of my windows form?

Tags: c#, asmx

In my solution I have two projects as web service and window application.

1. completed web service successfully
2. added the web reference to the window application

I have a gridview in my windows form. How could I display the output from the webservice, which is in the form of XML document, in my gridview?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
DataSet xyz = new DataSet();
xyz.ReadXml("c:\whatever.xml");
gridview.DataSource = xyz.Tables[0].DefaultView;
gridview.DataBind();
```